# How to prevent MacOS PreviewAPP from removing PKCS7 Signature

Tags: pdf, itext, adobe, preview, adobe-reader

Try this, open a digitally signed document in the Preview App in your Mac (you can use Adobe or any other software to sign) drag the signature and then save. Now open the file in Adobe Reader, the signature has been removed and converted to an AcroForm.

I already tried setting the CertificationLevel to not allow changes.

Code:

```
        String outputPath = getOutputPath(this.files.getDocumentPath());
        Certificate[] chain = {this.files.getCertificate()};
        IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(this.files.getPrivateKey(), "SHA-512", "BC");
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(this.files.getDocumentPath());
        StampingProperties properties = new StampingProperties();
        properties.useAppendMode();

        ImageData imgData = ImageDataFactory.create(this.files.getSignaturePath(), true);
        PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileOutputStream(outputPath), properties);
        signer.setFieldName(signatureName);

        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setPageNumber(page);
        appearance.setPageRect(this.rectangle);
        appearance.setSignatureGraphic(imgData);
        appearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC);
        signer.setCertificationLevel(PdfSigner.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);

        signer.signDetached(new BouncyCastleDigest(), pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

Docusign nailed this, cant seem to find a way to fix it.

Comment: *converted to an AcroForm* - what do you mean by that? Normal certification or approval signatures *are* in acroform anyways...

Comment: It removes the ByteRange and lets you sign the signature field which should be filled. 
In other words, it removes the signatures and just keeps the fillableform field

Comment: Ah, it clears the field value.

Comment: yes, which I found weird, I've been looking around and I cant seem able to find anything about that.

Comment: Stop using the PreviewApp - we also had lots of problems with it. But in its current form it is just broken...

Comment: *"Docusign nailed this"* - what do you mean by that?